# UI-grid wrap-text in each cell

Tags: angularjs, word-wrap, ui-grid

Using angularjs ui-grid, I have increased the rowHeight of the grid. I need to wrap the text in each cell and I need to get rid of the text truncation.

```
example http://plnkr.co/edit/9aoV9rkjf9eKpTjcAaC5?p=preview
```

Word wrap need to be done in name and description column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove

```
 -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

from

`.ui-grid-cell-contents`

and use   `word-break: break-all;`

```
.ui-grid-cell-contents {
  padding: 5px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  word-break: break-all;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

main.css:

```
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.ui-grid-cell-contents-break {
   padding: 5px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;


  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;

  word-break: break-all;
}
```

app.js:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'id' },
    { name: 'name'},
    { name: 'description',cellTemplate:'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents-break"> This is the test Description</div>'},
    { name: 'age', displayName: 'Age (not focusable)', allowCellFocus : false },
    { name: 'address.city' }
  ];
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6wDxSAfP8AE6zial4vhw?p=preview